# Structural Question Regarding pandas .drop method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oop

```
df2=df.drop(df[df['issue']=="prob"].index)
df2.head()
```

The code immediately below works fine.

But why is there a need to type **df[df[** rather than the below?

```
df2=df.drop(df['issue']=="prob"].index)
df2.head()
```

I know that the immediately above won't work while the former does. I would like to understand why or know what exactly I should google.

Also ~ any advice on a more relevant title would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: `df[df['issue']=="prob"]` produces a `DataFrame` with a **subset of values**.
- Option 2: `df['issue']=="prob"` produces a `pandas.Series` with a Boolean **for every row**.
- `.drop` works for Option 1, because it knows to just drop the selected indices, vs. all of the indices returned from Option 2.
- I would use the following methods to remove rows.

  - Use `~` (not) to select the opposite of the Boolean selection.

    - `df = df[~(df.treatment == 'Yes')]`
  - Select rows with only the desired value

    - `df = df[(df.treatment == 'No')]`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# sample dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
rows = 25
data = {'a': np.random.randint(10, size=(rows)),
        'groups': [random.choice(['1-5', '6-25', '26-100', '100-500', '500-1000', '>1000']) for _ in range(rows)],
        'treatment': [random.choice(['Yes', 'No']) for _ in range(rows)],
        'date': pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=rows).tolist()}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

### `df[df.treatment == 'Yes'].index`

- Produces just the indices where `treatment` is `'Yes'`, therefore `df.drop(df[df.treatment == 'Yes'].index)` only drops the indices in the list.

```py
df[df.treatment == 'Yes'].index

[out]:
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19, 21], dtype='int64')

df.drop(df[df.treatment == 'Yes'].index)

[out]:
    a    groups treatment       date
3   5      6-25        No 2020-08-15
5   2  500-1000        No 2020-08-17
9   0  500-1000        No 2020-08-21
10  3   100-500        No 2020-08-22
16  8       1-5        No 2020-08-28
17  4       1-5        No 2020-08-29
18  3       1-5        No 2020-08-30
20  6  500-1000        No 2020-09-01
22  6      6-25        No 2020-09-03
23  8   100-500        No 2020-09-04
24  9    26-100        No 2020-09-05
```

### `(df.treatment == 'Yes').index`

- Produces all of the indices, therefore `df.drop((df.treatment == 'Yes').index)` drops all of the indices, leaving an empty dataframe.

```py
(df.treatment == 'Yes').index

[out]:
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=25, step=1)

df.drop((df.treatment == 'Yes').index)

[out]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, groups, treatment, date]
Index: []
```